# Prevent user from exiting full screen mode in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I encounter this problem while I'm developing a interactive website for a touch enabled screen. Screen will be placed in a public area. So it needs to restrict user exiting the full screen mode in chrome and go to other applications of the computer. How can I restrict people exiting the full screen mode in chrome?

Comment: I'm trying the same thing. Do you have some solution now? Then please answer your question. A silly attempt using Linux and a touchscreen: Start Chrome in fullscreen via the undocumented `-kiosk` Option. Calibrate the touchscreen so that the top of the screen cannot be reached (usually permitted by the bezel anyway) so the user can't exit by the mouse pointer way. If a keyboard is attached, modify the keymap file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` and delete any command key like `Strg`, `F1`-`F12` etc. If using the on screen keyboard, you can define a custom layout ommiting such keys too.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue using -kiosk mode. Lucky, in my case there are no any mouse or keyboard attached to the computer.